# How to make Two Header Rows for table in UI5

Tags: javascript, binding, sapui5

The image uploaded with this question shows a table having two header rows. My header rows are grouped and are under another header row. How to make it possible in SAPUI5?

[image: table having two header rows grouped and are under another header row]

Comment: Thanks, How to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `sap.ui.table.Table` class and use the `multiLabels` aggregation from `sap.ui.table.Column` class by using different `sap.m.Label` with the same text for the common header between columns.

[Sample: Multi Header](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.ui.table.Table/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.MultiHeader)

[image]

```
<Column
    width="11rem"
    sortProperty="street"
    filterProperty="street"
    headerSpan="3,2">
    <multiLabels>
        <m:Label text="Contact" textAlign="Center" width="100%"/>
        <m:Label text="Address" textAlign="Center" width="100%"/>
        <m:Label text="Street" textAlign="Center" width="100%"/>
    </multiLabels>
    <template>
        <m:Text text="{street}" wrapping="false"/>
    </template>
</Column>
<Column
    width="11rem"
    sortProperty="city"
    headerSpan="2">
    <multiLabels>
        <m:Label text="Contact"/>
        <m:Label text="Address"/>
        <m:Label text="City" textAlign="Center" width="100%"/>
    </multiLabels>
    <template>
        <m:Input value="{city}"/>
    </template>
</Column>
<Column
    width="11rem"
    sortProperty="phone">
    <multiLabels>
        <m:Label text="Contact"/>
        <m:Label text="Phone" textAlign="Center" width="100%"/>
    </multiLabels>
    <template>
        <m:Input value="{phone}"/>
    </template>
</Column>
```